# Socket.io Chat Using MongoDB objectID in client side div?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jquery-ui, socket.io

**The technical background:**
For the chat application I am using node.js, socket.io, jquery, jquery-ui and mongodb for user and session storage.
It allows private messaging as well as chatting in rooms.

**The Question:**
For the private chats I am currently generating a new jquery ui tab in which the chat messages display. The problem is, the user is automatically created via e-mail from an external site and I don't want to use this mailadress as an id for the div that is created in jquery-ui. On the other hand, i need some information to determine to which user the private messages should go. **So I thought about using the mongoDB object id or at least the first let's say six characters of it. Is this a bad idea in terms of safety?**

*Note: please excuse my bad english*

Comment: What code have you tried so far? If I read this elsewhere, that would suggest this is a duplicate question and I would vote to close it. Please edit your post and include a proper example.

Comment: This is not a code related question, since there is no problem with the implementation. I just want to know, because of my lack of knowledge in terms of mongodb, if there can be security issues if multiple objectid's from mongodb are known to client. I mean, can he start some kind of attack with this id ? Sorry. I'm not so familar with mongodb architecture.

Comment: Well, maybe ask your customers if they want their email address exposed in the code of the web page. If a bot came across them, they could simply harvest all the addresses from the page and then start spamming your customers. If the ID is a number in your DB, that should be fine to use as long as your site is protected from SQL Injection.

Comment: It would only expose the email to users in the same chatroom dynamically and after authorization. Furthermore by now you can only reach the site within company network. The objectID is the autogenerated key from mongodb but i think you answered my question. Thank you. I was just unsure if there was any kind of nosql injection scenario which utilizes the mongodb key.